# MATLAB Optimization toolbox example

Tags: matlab, optimization

https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/examples/banana-function-minimization.html

```
fun = @(x)(100*(x(2) - x(1)^2)^2 + (1 - x(1))^2);
options = optimset('OutputFcn',@bananaout,'Display','off');
x0 = [-1.9,2];
[x,fval,eflag,output] = fminsearch(fun,x0,options);
title 'Rosenbrock solution via fminsearch'
Fcount = output.funcCount;
disp(['Number of function evaluations for fminsearch was ',num2str(Fcount)])
disp(['Number of solver iterations for fminsearch was ',num2str(output.iterations)])
```

What is `@bananaout` here?

This is giving me the following error,

```
??? Error using ==> feval
Attempt to execute SCRIPT bananaout as a function:
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\bananaout.m

Error in ==> callAllOptimOutputFcns at 12
    stop(i) = feval(OutputFcn{i},xOutputfcn,optimValues,state,varargin{:});

Error in ==> fminsearch>callOutputAndPlotFcns at 464
            stop = callAllOptimOutputFcns(outputfcn,xOutputfcn,optimValues,state,varargin{:})
            || stop;

Error in ==> fminsearch at 199
    [xOutputfcn, optimValues, stop] =
    callOutputAndPlotFcns(outputfcn,plotfcns,v(:,1),xOutputfcn,'init',itercount, ...

Error in ==> test_optim at 9
[x,fval,eflag,output] = fminsearch(fun,x0,options)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the doc, [Output Functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/output-functions.html) are called by the optimizer at every time step, enabling you to do things like plot the progress of the optimization.

In your case you get an error because `bananaout` seems to be a script when it needs to be a function (with specific inputs - see the doc for their details).  Did you happen to save the example code in a script called `bananaout`?  If so, rename the script.

You can see a list of all m-code that you have that are called `bananaout` by executing the following:

`>> which bananaout -all`

One of them will be the function that the example should be calling, while another will be the one that you have created and need to rename/remove.